# Linking my mac to a monitor but my backlight has gone

Tags: mac, screen

The back light on my mac screen has failed and I have the correct cables/connections to link to a monitor. The signal is coming through fine as I can see my wall paper. All my icons and files are to the "left" of the monitor screen, off screen but there. I can not get into system preferences to make the necessary changes as it is off screen. 
Does anyone know how I might be able to get round this problem. Thanks. Scott

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure. It is an older mac, 2008 I think. How can I check this?

Answer (score 1):

A keyboard shortcut used to be cmd-F1. You may also try fn-cmd-F1.

Check [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/6988/mac-whats-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-between-video-mirroring-and-and). It is rather old but has had recent updates.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked right away! Really appreciate this.